# Select data between timestamp x and timestamp y returned as z amount of rows (scaled down result set)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select data between 2 given timestamps returned as a given amount of rows.

There's 3 variables to take into account;

- timestamp 1
- timestamp 2
- amount of data points

So far I have this (and that kinda works) but doesn't return the wanted amount of rows. In the query below I'm trying to select **250 records** between **2019-07-14** and **2019-07-15**, but it returns 48 rows.

```sql
SELECT
    AVG(`value`) AS `avg`,
    `createdAt` AS `dtime`,
    `createdAt` * 1 AS `dtime_int`,
    ROUND(
        `createdAt` / (
            (CONVERT('2019-07-15', DATETIME) - CONVERT('2019-07-14', DATETIME)
        ) / 250)
    ) AS `groupBy`
FROM `samples`
WHERE `createdAt` BETWEEN '2019-07-14' AND '2019-07-15'
GROUP BY `groupBy`
ORDER BY `dtime` DESC;
```

So I'm guessing this isn't the best approach. Any and all suggestions are welcome!

Edit: this is a test data set I'm using and where I'm keeping progress: [`samples.sql`](https://gist.github.com/wouterds/5c80f48d9a07654947cb3f4c96977025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is probably the `between`.  In all likelihood, `createdAt` is a datetime, so the time component interferes with what you want to do.

I strongly advise you to use direct comparisons.  If you want both days, then:

```
WHERE createdAt >= '2019-07-14' AND
      createdAt < '2019-07-16'
```

If you want only 2019-07-14:

```
WHERE createdAt >= '2019-07-14' AND
      createdAt < '2019-07-15'
```

Splitting this into a given number of rows is not really possible.  After all, all the timestamps could be the same and then how would you get different bins?

But you can split this into equal sized bins:

```
SELECT floor( (timestampdiff(second, '2019-07-15', createdat) /
               timestampdiff(second, '2019-07-15', '2019-07-17')
              ) * 48
            ) as grp,
       AVG(`value`) AS `avg`
FROM samples s
WHERE createdAt >= '2019-07-14' AND
      createdAt < '2019-07-16'
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp DESC;
```

Comment: That looks promising, I'm going to experiment a bit with it!